# Ignite WAL Archive purge

Tags: ignite, gridgain

We do have three nodes Ignite cluster. Out of 3 nodes I can see in one node WAL Archive path is full. Is there any way to clear that? Like currently WAL directory having todays data but WAL Archive directory having last 3 days data/old wal segments. So how to configure for the old archives which are not requried will be removed/purged by Ignite automatcally.

Answer (score 2):

Wal Archive is automatically maintained by Ignite, and recycled on a regular basis per the checkpointing process. https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/persistence-checkpointing

You can configure the size of the Wal Archive, but not what data is stored there.

see: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/write-ahead-log#tuning-wal-archive

Comment: thanks for the reply. However as I said in one my cluster node the WAL archive path is full and there is no space for further archive. How I resolve this issue? Due to this no WAL also generated since the archive path is full.

Comment: you can either turn on wal archive compaction or turn off wal archiving
https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/write-ahead-log#wal-archive-compaction

Comment: But why the WAL archive path got full only for one node whereas for rest of the nodes it's working fine

Comment: My guess is that it's possible due to some uneven data distribution. Are you caches replicated? Is it possible that most of the requests come into the particular node?

Comment: @Alexandr Shapkin Yes, our caches are partitioned with 1 backup copy and it's a 3 node cluster with baseline topology defined. Yes most of cases we login to 1st node to connect to Ignite and do our operations. However, everytime 3rd node WAL archive get full. Request your help if you share how to configure the frequency of checkpointing.

Comment: @sandipbhowmik Yes, that makes sense. But initially, when I was referring to the data distribution, I meant the following scenario: say, you've designed a <city, person[]> cache and you want to store the NYC with 10 million records and 100 other cities with 10k population. In such case, the data is going to be shifted toward this one particular partition. I think you can use cache metrics or the WebConsole to check the partition sizes.

Comment: @Alexandr Shapkin Thanks for the suggestion. Could you share the steps to configure the frequency of checkpointing.

Comment: @sandipbhowmik Please, take a look  DataStorageConfiguration setCheckpointFrequency https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/configuration/DataStorageConfiguration.html#setCheckpointFrequency-long- if it's still valid.

Comment: @AlexandrShapkin Thanks. Is that possible to share the necessary xml config for the same.